# Determine location of an alias in Unix (or Mac)

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I have a Mac at work and my coworker set up an alias for me so that when I type `git-tf` at the command prompt it runs /opt/git-tf-2.0.1/git-tf.  However I'm not sure how he did this.  My $PATH variable does not include /opt/git-tf-2.0.1, nor can I find a script by the name git-tf in any of the directories listed in $PATH. The commands `whereis git-tf` and `which git-tf` have not been of any help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are simply mappings of one command to another. You can list them by typing `alias` in terminal, and set them by typing `alias name=value` (e.g., `alias rm=rm-i`)

Your coworker likely added an alias command to one of the config files that are sourced when your terminal starts. I'd start by looking in ~/.profile, if it exists. Otherwise, you can probably do a search for the alias command in question to find the file.

Other config file locations, as listed by [sixtyfootersdude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622711/1286571):

- /etc/profile
- ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_logout
- ~/.bashrc

For more info on aliases, type `man alias`.

Comment: I forgot about `alias`.  Thanks!  And thanks for the location of config file locations.  I feel like such a newb for even having to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

look in your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` files. 
You can try searching for the aliases thus-:

```
cd $HOME
grep alias *
```

Comment: .bash_profile is just what I was looking for!  Thanks!  `grep alias *` didn't work for me though.  :-(

Answer (score -1):

You have to modify/create a `.bashrc` file into your home directory, and inside that file you must insert:

```
PATH=/opt/git-tf-2.0.1/:$PATH
```

That line will cause you append the desired directory in your current path

after you must exec `source .bashrc` from a console

Finally try exec:

```
git-tf
```